# Where is the place to register a Jackson Codec in Vertx 4.0 using custom Object Mapper

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-verticle

I am trying to convert [my Quarkus vertex sample](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/blob/master/vertx-routes/) to pure [Vertx 4.0](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/blob/master/post-service/) and encountered a problem.

In Quarkus, it is easy to customize the Jackson ObjectMapper to serialize or deserialize the HTTP messages.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class CustomObjectMapper implements ObjectMapperCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
        objectMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);
        objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.READ_DATE_TIMESTAMPS_AS_NANOSECONDS);

        JavaTimeModule module = new JavaTimeModule();
        LocalDateTimeDeserializer localDateTimeDeserializer = new LocalDateTimeDeserializer(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME);
        module.addDeserializer(LocalDateTime.class, localDateTimeDeserializer);
        objectMapper.registerModule(module);
    }
}
```

And in Vertx, how to customize the `ObjectMapper` gracefully? My intention is registering a custom `ObjectMapper` instead of the built-in one, thus when using `Json.encode`, it will use my custom `objectMapper` instead.

In [my Vertx sample](https://github.com/hantsy/vertx-sandbox/blob/master/post-service/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostsHandler.java#L32), the `Json.encode` will use the built-in `objectMapper` to serialize the Java 8 DateTime to an int array instead of an ISO date string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need to add `jackson-databind` to your dependencies because Vert.x 4 does not bring transitively.

Then in your main method:

```
io.vertx.core.json.jackson.DatabindCodec codec = (io.vertx.core.json.jackson.DatabindCodec) io.vertx.core.json.Json.CODEC;
// returns the ObjectMapper used by Vert.x
ObjectMapper mapper = codec.mapper();
// returns the ObjectMapper used by Vert.x when pretty printing JSON
ObjectMapper prettyMapper = codec.prettyMapper();
```

Now you can configure both mappers

Comment: Vertx configured a `DatabindCodec`(of course, I included databind, and jsr310 module) using JacksonFactory which defined an `ObjectMapper` there. I do not know how to configure it. For my application, when I call `Json` methods in the handlers, the Java 8 Datetime is not serialized to a string but an int array(it is a general problem in Java can be fixed by adjusting the parameters of ObjectMapper).

Comment: For me (VertX 4.0.3) `mapper()` and `prettyMapper()` are static methods on `DatabindCodec`. So accessing the `Json` class and casting the codec seems unnecessary. You can access the mapper directly, e.g. `DatabindCodec.mapper()`.